Explanation of a step in Jech's Set Theory Theorem 2.8
The following is from Jech's Set Theory. I'm struggling to understand why $y_1\in \text{ran}(f)$:

Theorem 2.8 If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are well-ordered sets, then exactly one of the following three cases holds:

$W_1$ is isomorphic to $W_2$;
$W_1$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $W_2$;
$W_2$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $W_1$.

Proof: For $u \in W_i$, ($i = 1, 2$), let $W_i(u)$ denote the initial segment of $W_i$ given by $u$. Let
$$
f = \{(x, y) \in W_1 \times W_2 : W_1(x) \text{ is isomorphic to } W_2(y)\}.
$$
Using Lemma 2.7, it is easy to see that $f$ is a one-to-one function. If $h$ is an isomorphism between $W_1(x)$ and $W_2(y)$, and $x' < x$, then $W_1(x')$ and $W_2(h(x'))$ are isomorphic. It follows that $f$ is order-preserving. If $\text{dom}(f) = W_1$ and $\text{ran}(f) = W_2$, then case (i) holds. If $y_1 < y_2$ and $y_2 \in \text{ran}(f)$, then $y_1 \in \text{ran}(f)$ [...]


$y_2 \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$ means that $y_2 = f(x_2)$ for some $x_2$. Thus there exists an isomorphism $h : W(x_2) \to W(y_2)$. Since $y_1 \in W(y_2)$, we get the element $x_1 = h^{-1}(y_1) \in W(x_2)$. Clearly $x_1 < x_2$. Hence $W(x_1)$ and $W(h(x_1)) = W(y_1)$ are isomorphic. This shows $y_1 = f(x_1)$, i.e. $y_1 \in \operatorname{ran}(f)$.
